# How to connect Node.js app to postgresql on Ubuntu server?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg, node-postgres

I started the server. Installed there nodejs, nginx, postgres, ufw and more. The site is working. Problem connecting to postgres. I started the server. Installed there nodejs, nginx, postgres, ufw and more. The site is working. The problem is connecting to postgres. It is in the connection, not in the query, because I have tried many sql queries, but it just ignores client.query(). 
Postgres default settings and configuration. I didn’t change anything.

in the configuration file #listening_address is comment.

Used by node-postgres.

```
const { Client } = require('pg');
const client = new Client({
  user: 'admin', //tried postgres
  host: '127.0.0.1', //tried *, site ip
  database: 'passport', //tried other DB
  password: 'secretpass', //installed through $passwd postgres, #ALTER USER admin with password ''
  port: 5432,
});
client.connect();

app.post('/confirm', urlencodedParser, function (req, res){
  let uid = uuidv4();
  let query= {
    text : 'INSERT INTO users(uid, name, surname, birthday, gender, email, password, region, language) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9);',
    values : [uid, user.name, user.surname, user.birthday, user.gender, user.email, user.password, user.region, user.region]
  }

  client.query(query, (err, result) => { // I have tried many sql queries, but it just ignores client.query()

    // console.log('some text');  doesn't display
    if (err) {
      console.log(err.stack)
    } else {
        res.render('addsite', {user: user});
      }
  });
});
```

/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf

```
# i didn't change anything
data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main'
hba_file = '/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf'
ident_file = '/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_ident.conf'

external_pid_file = '/var/run/postgresql/9.5-main.pid'
port = 5432 
max_connections = 100
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql' 
ssl = true
ssl_cert_file = '/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem'
ssl_key_file = '/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key'
shared_buffers = 128MB
dynamic_shared_memory_type = posix
log_line_prefix = '%t [%p-%l] %q%u@%d '
log_timezone = 'Etc/UTC'
stats_temp_directory = '/var/run/postgresql/9.5-main.pg_stat_tmp'

datestyle = 'iso, mdy'
timezone = 'Etc/UTC'
lc_messages = 'en_US.UTF-8' 
lc_monetary = 'en_US.UTF-8' 
lc_numeric = 'en_US.UTF-8'
lc_time = 'en_US.UTF-8'

default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'
```

/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

help me, please!!!

Answer (score 0):

Hey you all need to use `connect` method of pg to connect with database.

After adding configuration:

```
client.connect()
```

Only then you can start query on your database.

For more information check this link on connecting: https://node-postgres.com/features/connecting

Answer (score 0):

As your pg_hba.conf looks like not touched.
Look to that lines:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer    
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
```

This is telling you the database could only be accessed be peer authentication mode.
To do that you should access the database with postgres credentials.

```
$sudo su postgres
```

after that you should be prompted password for your super user in linux. After password with success you should see the your bash prompt label change to:

```
postgres@<yourlinuxinstance>
```

Now you can access postgres database with peer authentication mode.

```
$psql -U postgres
#should login in postgres with success
postgres=#
```

In psql command line you should now create the user and password to access the database.

```
CREATE USER foo WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '-+mysecurepasswordforthisuser+-';
CREATE DATABASE passport;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON passport TO foo;
\q #exit psql shell
$exit #exit from su session with postgres username
```

After that you should must access the pg_hba.conf file and change access method, change `peer` to `md5`

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
```

Restart the database

```
$sudo service postgresql restart
```

After that you can configure the current added user password and database in your connection string.

Now you should access your database from your nodejs code with success.

If you need some clarifications you can [access this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-18-04-pt)